# AutoComplete and backspace key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a very basic autocomplete with tag generation for my website. I am having a problem when removing tags on the backspace key. Here is how I handle the backspace...

```
var txt = elem.val();
var tagArray = [];

if(keyCode === 8 && !txt && tagArray.length > 0){
    $(".mytag:last").remove();
    tagArray.splice(-1,1);
}
```

I have tried using **.on("keydown")** and every once in a while it erases multiple items I assume because on keydown fires multiple times for backspace depending on the length you hold the button down.

**EDIT**
New development, on.("keydown") works until I blur the field then it removes tag item

I have also tried **.on("keyup")** and once my txt field is empty than remove, but of course when you are on the last char when you keyup the field is empty so it removes the last char plus one of my tags.

How can I use the backspace key to erase my text field and then when it is empty start erasing tags without these errors?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle to demo the problem you're experiencing? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! When using the keydown event it was incrementing the event everytime I blurred and refocused the on the element. I solved this by unbinding the event from the element